# How can I grant user consent to a 3rd party enterprise application via Azure PowerShell?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2b

We have an Azure PowerShell script to automate the provisioning of resources in our customers' subscription. As part of the process we deploy a VM based off a custom image hosted in our own image gallery. In order to do so we require our customers to grant access (user consent) to our enterprise application in their tenants.

As of now we achieve that through an OAuth2 link that we ask them to edit with their own tenant ID and open in browser:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/<customer-tenant-id>/oauth2/authorize?client_id=cd3df191-153a-4ae1-9766-5fe7a7f3032e&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com`

This link authenticates them and asks for the requested permissions to be accepted:

[image]

After that, our enterprise application should be listed in their subscriptions with the following permissions:

[image]

***We would like for this pre-requisite to be addressed programmatically by our deployment script. Is there any way we can achieve that via Azure PowerShell?***

To no avail, I've checked quite a few pages online and several similar questions here on SO. They are different in the sense that they are requesting **Admin Consent** rather than **User Consent** (mind that ours only require User Consent, see screenshot below). Also, some questions are specific to Azure CLI or simply Azure Portal (not an option for us as we are working with Azure PowerShell).

[image]

PS: Sorry in advance for my lack of knowledge in regards to Azure AD and the Consent Framework in general.

Comment: Have you tried using the common endpoint as it seems your app is multitenant. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#update-your-code-to-send-requests-to-common) for more info on how to let AAD discover the tenant id that the user belongs to. I think with the common endpoint you can programmatically do this without the manual way of setting the tenant id.

Answer (score 1):

Consent can be used to grant app roles (application permissions) and delegated permissions.

What you're trying to do here is to create a delegated permission grant. Specifically, you're trying to grant a delegated permission on behalf of an individual user (instead of on behalf of all users).

You can't do this with Azure PowerShell.

You can, however, do this with [Microsoft Graph PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/powershell/installation). The cmdlet you use, will be [New-MgOauth2PermissionGrant](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.identity.signins/new-mgoauth2permissiongrant?view=graph-powershell-beta). This cmdlet calls the Microsoft Graph API to [create a delegated permission grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/oauth2permissiongrant-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). The PowerShell cmdlet requires the following parameters:

- `ClientId` - The object ID of the client app's service principal. This is the service principal which will be gaining privileges.
- `ConsentType` - In this case, this should be "Principal", indicating you want to grant this delegated permission on behalf of a single principal (a user).
- `PrincipalId` - This is the object ID of the user on behalf of who the client app will be able to act.
- `ResourceId` - The object ID of the API's service principal. This is the service principal representing the API that exposes the delegated permissions you want to grant.
- `Scope` - The space-separated list of permissions to grant.

So, for example, if we wanted to grant the Microsoft Graph delegated permission *User.Read*, on behalf of user with user principal name bob@example.com, we could do the following:

```
$userUpn = "bob@example.com"
$clientAppId = "738a2731-dd81-4263-824b-74cf6dee9da0"
$resourceSpn = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
$scope = "User.Read"

# Retrieve the user, and the client and resource service principals
$user = Get-MgUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$userUpn'"
$client = Get-MgServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '$clientAppId'"
$resource = Get-MgServicePrincipal -Filter "servicePrincipalNames/any(n:n eq '$resourceSpn')"

# Grant the delegated permissions for Microsoft Graph to the client, on behalf of the user
$grant = New-MgOAuth2PermissionGrant `
    -ClientId $client.Id `
    -ConsentType "Principal" `
    -PrincipalId $user.Id `
    -ResourceId $resource.Id `
    -Scope $scope
```